# Failed to read Firebase options from the app's resources

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I get the error  `Failed to read Firebase options from the app's resources. Either make sure google-services.json is included in your build or specify options explicitly.`
When building the unity game to android, even though it works in the editor.

I have tried all the solutions of previous questions. Notably, I don't have a mainTemplate.gradle file, and inside /Plugins/Android I don't have a firebase folder. I am using the .net framework, and I enabled arm64. I also have the googleservices.json both in the assets folder and streamingassets folder. Are there any other solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to build to an android project, you need to have a keystore file and I didn't have one. Here is a link to explain how to create the keystore file:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/database/testapp